# Driver's license stolen... from a state I no longer have any connection to... how do I get a replacement?

Tags: us-citizens, driving-license, identification

I am originally from Massachusetts but moved to Dallas, Texas for work several years ago. At that time, I switched my MA license to a TX license. Since then, I have moved to Asia. Two weeks ago, while traveling for work, my wallet - with my license - was stolen. I have two questions:

1. I cannot prove residency in Texas anymore since I don't live there... but my license should still be valid, it's just stolen. How do I get a replacement?
2. My MA license expired last year. The RMV website says I can renew a license up to four years after it expires. Can I still do this even though I switched license from MA to TX? I still have mail that goes to an address in MA as I have family there - I can use this a residency.

Thanks for your help! This is such a pain... I am an American and want a driver's license for when I go back (unfortunately this year I will not be going to Texas OR Massachusetts...) but without a permanent residency it is proving really difficult!!

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should be getting a license from the country where you now live in Asia.

Comment: Check the instructions on this page -https://www.txdps.state.tx.us/DriverLicense/nonmilitaryrenewal.htm You would need to provide residency in Texas. and legally you can only hold drivers license for one state at a time so you had to actually not use your MA license once you had a TX license